# Lambda expression select and combine fields as single string

Tags: c#, string, lambda

Let's say , I have `tableOne` as this structure

```
Name            Age
=========================
John            34
Ammy            23
Joe             16
Sam             18
```

What I want to get is likes this format in a **single string**

```
John (34) , Ammy (23) , Joe (16) , Sam (18)
```

How can I get this in a short way using **lambda expression** ? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What have I tried ? Just select as a List Siva :) `tableOne.ToList()`

Comment: @zey I think what *Siva* means is, what have you tried to do to produce a string like that? Even if your attempt didn't work or didn't even compile, at least it shows that you tried something. People on SO are generally forgiving of bad code, but we usually want to see some code :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var result = string.Join(",", tableOne.Select(x=>string.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Name, x.Age)));
```

Answer (score 4):

[*Damith*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17939481/1715579) is excellent, and actually cleaner, but if you need to use this with entity framework or some other ORM, you'd probably have to do something like this:

```
var result = String.Join(" , ", 
    tableOne.Select(x => x.Name + " (" + x.Age + ")"));
```

Comment: BTW you don't need to call `ToString()` on integer when concatenating it with string